# ¿Cómo respondo mi propia pregunta?

Tags: soporte, faq, respuesta-propia

Esta es una pregunta auto-respuesta. La intención es como recordatorio a los nuevos usuarios.

¿Cómo respondo mi propia pregunta en este sitio (*StackOverflow en español*)?

[Regresar al índice del FAQ](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Muy fácil, hay dos maneras, una es responder luego de haber creado la pregunta, y la otra es crear una pregunta junto con la respuesta.

## 1. Responder luego de haber creado la pregunta.

Una vez que uno está en la pregunta, ir bajando hasta ver un botón que dice **Responde a tu Pregunta**.

[image: Responde a tu Pregunta]

## 2. Crear una pregunta junto con la respuesta.

Para hacer una pregunta junto con la respuesta, primero hay que clickear en el botón **Formular una pregunta**.

[image: Formular una pregunta]

Luego de eso, hay que marcar una casilla que permite incluir la respuesta junto a la pregunta.

La línea donde está la casilla, dice lo siguiente (el enlace te lleva al blog de StackOverflow, que está en inglés):

> **Responde a tu propia pregunta** – [comparte tu conocimiento, al estilo de preguntas y respuestas](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

[image: Responde a tu propia pregunta]

Al clickearlo, aparecerá otra caja de texto, para llenarla con la respuesta. Una vez que está todo completo, hay que clickear en el botón, **Publica tu pregunta y tu respuesta**.

[image: Publica tu pregunta y tu respuesta]

Comment: Agregaría a tu respuesta que solo puedes **aceptar tu respuesta** luego de 24 horas _si no estoy equivocado_. Lo ideal es que las preguntas no queden abiertas.