# ¿Qué quiere decir "Responde a tu propia pregunta – comparte tu conocimiento, al estilo de preguntas y respuestas"?

Tags: soporte, respuesta-propia

Cuando creo una nueva pregunta siempre veo esto:

**Responde a tu propia pregunta – comparte tu conocimiento, al estilo de preguntas y respuestas**

¿Significa que creo una pregunta y la contesto al mismo tiempo? En tal caso, ¿se publicaría la pregunta como wiki?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La característica a la que haces referencia tiene la etiqueta [respuesta-propia](/questions/tagged/respuesta-propia) la cual he agregado a la pregunta.

Si optas por publicar de forma simultánea la respuesta a la pregunta, sólo pasa eso, se publican la pregunta y la respuesta al mismo tiempo. Más detalles en [¿Cómo respondo mi propia pregunta?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1301/65).

Cabe agregar que para publicar "como wiki" hay una casilla especial que de forma predeterminada **no** está marcada. Sobre "los wiki" tenemos la etiqueta [wiki-de-comunidad](/questions/tagged/wiki-de-comunidad) donde puedes revisar las preguntas que ya se han respondido sobre este tipo de publicaciones.